# Finding Images folder

Tags: php, html, image, path, directory

Okay, I feel really bad asking this question,

but this is frustrating and I can't find the answer.

I am running Localhost with WAMP and using PHPstorm, anyway.

My problem is, I cannot figure out how to reach the images directory, before you try to answer, let me map this out for you.

so my rootfile is on my desktop:

Root: christmaslist 
Folder: php
-index.php
-header.php

Folder: images
-santa.png

Folder: uploads

Now, when I add a img tag to my index.php file

```
 <img id="site_logo" src='images/santa.png' alt='The Santa Logo' >
```

it appears in the browser as the broken image icon.

How do I make this work?

I'm a beginner ( no $H!T, but working on this currently)
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/22/create-a-christmas-wish-list-with-php/

Comment: try src='../images/santa.png' ??

Comment: I love you (:

all of the books I've read, all the tutorials and this was never mentioned. Thanks!!

Comment: I have posted it as an answer. You can mark it as accepted for others to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To future and current rookies/amateurs and burnouts, it's

```
" src="../images/image.png">"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

**src='../images/santa.png'**

What it does is - 'takes you to parent directory and then tries to find the "images" folder'.